# Using a constructor in a function call?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, arguments

I've been searching awhile for a good explanation of why/why not the following use of the `struct` constructor as a function argument is legal. Can someone provide one?

```
// Begin simple illustrative example C++ program    
#include<vector.h>

struct Item  
{  
  Item(double data, const int lead)
  : m_grid(data), m_lead(lead) {}

  double m_grid;
  int m_lead;
};

int main()
{
  double img = 0.0;
  int steps = 5;
  std::vector<Item> images;
  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
  {
    img += 2.0;
    images.push_back(Item(img,i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I was under the impression a constructor has neither a return type nor statement...

Comment: Is it C++? Please specify your language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is legal.

You never call the constructor yourself; you're actually just declaring an unnamed or "temporary" object of type `Item`. See how the syntax evolves when you make the object unnamed:

```
Item a(img,i); // normal
Item(img,i);   // temporary
```

Even though it looks as if you're calling the constructor like a function, you're not.

Anyway, you can use the temporary as an "rvalue" (because it is one) in function arguments and the like, which is what you're doing here.

---

BTW, don't use the old `iostream.h` and `vector.h` headers. They predate 1998. In ISO Standard C++, you should use `iostream` and `vector` respectively. Standard headers in C++ do not end in ".h" (inb4, ignoring the C headers inherited for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 8):

It's not the constructor or its return value that's passed to `push_back`. C++ actually uses the constructor to create a nameless temporary object, which exists only for the duration of the function call; typically, on the stack. This is then passed to `push_back`, and `push_back` copies its contents into your vector.

Answer (score 4):

This is legal, because `push_back`  takes it's argument by const reference, and then creates a copy of the object. The call of the constructor creates a temporary object, which is an rvalue. A const reference can bind an rvalue. The method cannot modify the object it is passed, but it can create a copy.

Comment: No, the programmer never calls the constructor. I know what you're saying but I think that your words are misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Although it looks like a function call, the expression *Item(img,i)* is actually the creation of a temporary object. The difference is that in runtime, memory will be allocated for the object on the stack, and then the constructor will be called, whereas if this were a regular function call no memory would be allocated.

Comment: Plus all the other things involved in constructing an object.